# An identity for elementary automorphisms of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\newcommand{\ad}{\text{ad}}$ $\newcommand{\Ad}{\text{Ad}}$
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra and let $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ be nilpotent. Then $\ad X$ is nilpotent and $\exp \ad X$ acts on $\mathfrak{g}$ via the adjoint representation of $G$ (**is this correct here?** I am not sure if I may be interpreting it incorrectly, since there is in fact no mention to a Lie/algebraic group $G$).
I want to show that, for any $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$,
$$ \ad \left( \exp(\ad X) Y \right) = \exp (\ad X) \ad Y \exp(-\ad X).$$
I know that $\Ad(\exp X) = \exp (\ad X)$ for any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ (in particular, $\exp$ and $\ad$ do not 'commute').

If I start from the left-hand side, I get
$$ \ad \left( \exp(\ad X) Y \right) = \ad \left( \Ad(\exp X) Y \right) = \ad (\exp X) \ad Y \ad (\exp -X).$$
If I start from the right-hand side, I get
$$ \exp (\ad X) \ad Y \exp(-\ad X) = \Ad(\exp (\ad X)) (\ad Y) = \exp (\ad (\ad X)) (\ad Y).$$
Neither of these give the identity, although they are almost there.

Comment: How are you getting ${\rm ad}({\rm Ad}(\exp X)Y)={\rm ad}(\exp X){\rm ad}Y{\rm ad}(\exp-X)$? The latter expression seems to be ${\rm Ad}({\rm ad}\exp X)Y$, are you mixing up ${\rm ad}$ and $\rm Ad$ or am I missing something.

Comment: As I understand it, $\Ad (\exp X)Y = \exp X Y \exp (-X)$, but this is probably wrong. In any case, your answer solves my problem, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, but my question was how you were getting ${\rm ad}({\rm Ad}(\exp X)Y)={\rm ad}(\exp X){\rm ad}Y{\rm ad}(\exp-X)$. How are you getting that latter expression? Maybe you meant ${\rm ad}((\exp X)Y(\exp -X))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind $\Phi=\mathrm{Ad}\exp X=\exp\mathrm{ad}X$ is a lie algebra homomorphism, so

$$ \mathrm{ad}(\Phi Y)Z=[\Phi Y,Z]=\Phi[Y,\Phi^{-1}Z]=\Phi\circ\mathrm{ad}Y\circ\Phi^{-1} $$

which is what you wanted. In short,

$$ \mathrm{ad}((\exp\mathrm{ad}X)Y)=(\mathrm{Ad}\exp\mathrm{ad}X)Y. $$